# phpseclib wordpress integration not working

Tags: phpseclib

i am trying to run phpseclib with Wordpress but its not logging in. the same code runs on PHP Designer 8 which has PHP v 5.* but on word press with PHP 7.3* and PHP 7.4 its not running. I got 2 error in Eventviewer

1. sshd: Bad packet length 980908999. [preauth]
2. sshd: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 15412: message authentication code incorrect [preauth]
   SFTP server is Openssh
   it gives 2 warnings on the webpage as follows. Can someone guide please. thanks.

Warning: unpack(): Type C: not enough input, need 1, have 0 in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\testing\wp-content\plugins\sftp\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 1345

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\testing\wp-content\plugins\sftp\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 1345

> $sftp = new Net_SFTP('127.0.0.1',22); $sftp->getLog(); if
> (!$sftp->login('myuser', 'pass')) { //if you can't log on...
> $sftp->getLog();    echo $sftp->getErrors();
> print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());    echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
> exit('sftp Login Failed'); } echo $sftp->pwd();

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you running? Maybe copy / paste your Net/SSH2.php file into pastebin.com and post the link.

Comment: Yes it was version problem, in my site the phpseclib was version 1. and it took long time to understand whats going on. Thank you very much. Plus the functions inside are also replaced to new SFTP.

Comment: Plus the functions inside are also replaced to new SFTP. This came with wordpress SFTP updater, this is old, they should update it. plus PHP designer is using PHP5 dont know why

Comment: Version 1 of phpseclib is actively maintained. I wasn't asking about the version to see if you were running v1 or v2 of phpseclib - I was asking to see if you were running 1.0.19 vs 1.0.1 or something. If updating phpseclib worked then my guess is that you simply had an out of date version of https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/ (if that's the plugin your talking about).

Comment: I installed it via wordpress. so i was expecting updated version.

Comment: If you installed it recently then yah I'd expect an updated version too...  Well I guess you got it working anywho so good job lol